# Save huge amount of Strings in file during program execution in Java

Tags: java, string, memory, memory-management

In my program the main logic is to construct **Strings** in different methods and then to save them in a specific order in a file. But my memory consumption is very high, so I wonder how to save less strings in memory. So I will try to simplify the program for the ease of reading here. My small String Generating methods do like:

Then my main logic is something like:

```
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
        for(int i=1;i<1_000_000_000;i++){
            bw.write(processMethod(i));
        }
        bw.close();
```

where the `processMethod` is a method that calls methods like `generateTag` **m** times, makes String using `StringBuilder` and then saves to `BufferedWriter` .

```
public static String generateTag(final String tagName, final String name, final String value) {
        StringBuilder attribute = new StringBuilder();
        attribute.append("<tag:");
        attribute.append(tagName);
        attribute.append(" name=\"");
        attribute.append(name);
        attribute.append("\">");
        attribute.append(value);
        attribute.append("</tag:");
        attribute.append(tagName);
        attribute.append(">");
        return attribute.toString();
    }
```

So when I start the `processMethod` executes **1_000_000_000** times and then m times is called `generateTag` like methods. I have **1_000_000_000** * **m** strings in the memory. How can I easily remove their creation? I think something like:

```
public static String generateTag(final String tagName, final String name, final String value, final BufferedWriter bf) {
   ....
   bf.write(someBuilder.toString());
   ..

}
```

But passing `BufferedWriter` around is not a good I  think.
Can you suggest me some less String created description.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Why aren't you writing directly to the file instead of keeping the strings in memory? That is, why do you think passing the `BufferedWriter` around is bad?

Comment: But how to do that to open new BufferWrite to file in every method and to pass around just the absolute path to file?

Comment: No, you pass just the main `BufferedWriter` from the main through the `processMethod`. Only one `BufferedWriter`, otherwise they won't be writing to the same file sequentially, right?

Comment: Not a real solution, but you should consider using the G1GC garbage collector with enabled string deduplication. This can save you a lot of memory

Comment: You have to pass something around so that every call to generateTag does not end up producing a string. BufferedWriter, Writer or StringBuilder or ByteBuffer - your call.

Comment: @Svetlin Zarev: the reason, why you need a certain garbage collector for string deduplication, is, that these duplicates are identified during the collection. But at that point, these temporary strings are already garbage, not subject to deduplication.

Answer (score 4):

If indeed your program merely calls methods one after the other and those methods generate strings and those strings are written to the file in the order they are generated, then it's simpler to write directly to the file using the main `BufferedWriter`:

```
try (BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);) {
    for(int i=1;i<1_000_000_000;i++){
        processMethod(i, bw);
    }
}
```

(Note that I used try-with-resources to automatically close the buffered writer).

And then when `processMethod` calls `generateTag`, it passes the buffered writer to it:

```
public void processMethod(int i, BufferedWriter bw) {
    ...
    generateTag(...,bw);
    ...
}
```

And `generateTag` is going to be:

```
public static void generateTag(final String tagName, final String name, final String value, final BufferedWriter bw) {
        bw.write("<tag:");
        bw.write(tagName);
        bw.write(" name=\"");
        bw.write(name);
        bw.write("\">");
        bw.write(value);
        bw.write("</tag:");
        bw.write(tagName);
        bw.write(">");
    }
```

Since `BufferedWriter` is buffered, it means that there is disk access not every time you call `write`, but every time the buffer is filled up. So this won't cost you in disk access speed. But it will save you all that memory.

Of course, if you don't write the results serially, or the result of one method depends on the result of the other, then you need to modify this, but still, you should write as soon as you have the next piece of `String` ready.

Answer (score 1):

One thing you may consider is to not saving them in memory, and instead write them as soon as possible...

many XML api like jdom, dom and dom4j abet the harmful habits of building tree model in memory, whereas in reality, it is far more efficient to dump the byte out into output buffer asap...

You could rewrite your method to include an output stream variable and flush out all the bytes out with the output stream.

Comment: Yes, that will be better. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`Appendable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Appendable.html) abstraction to ensure the `generateTag` (and likewise `processMethod`, if you wish) have no dependency to `BufferedWriter`. In fact, we can even pass a `StringBuilder` to do the same as before, a feature, which we can use to provide an appropriate overload:

```
public static CharSequence generateTag(
    final String tagName, final String name, final String value) {

    StringBuilder attribute=new StringBuilder(80);
    try { generateTag(tagName, name, value, attribute); }
    catch (IOException ex) { throw new AssertionError(ex); }
    return attribute;
}
public static void generateTag(
    final String tagName, final String name, final String value, Appendable attribute)
    throws IOException {

    attribute.append("<tag:");
    attribute.append(tagName);
    attribute.append(" name=\"");
    attribute.append(name);
    attribute.append("\">");
    attribute.append(value);
    attribute.append("</tag:");
    attribute.append(tagName);
    attribute.append(">");
}
```

Note that the overload returns `CharSequence` rather than `String` to be able to omit the final `StringBuilder.toString()` copying step. Unfortunately, calling `append(CharSequence)`on the `BufferedWriter` with it would not pay off, given the [current implementation](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/io/Writer.java#223). Still there are [APIs allowing to use `CharSequence` directly](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/class-use/CharSequence.html).

Comment: So if I do in that way I can pass varaibles from types which implements Appendable: BufferedWriter, CharArrayWriter, CharBuffer, FileWriter, FilterWriter, LogStream, OutputStreamWriter, PipedWriter, PrintStream, PrintWriter, StringBuffer, StringBuilder, StringWriter, Writer.

But if at run time has BufferedWriter then toString() will be called on append? Other APIs use not Buffered version, which can be a problem.

Comment: No, no, if you use `generateTag(tagName,name,value,bufferedWriter)`, no temporary strings are created. Only if you use `bufferedWriter.append(generateTag(tagName,name,value))`, the `CharSequence` will be converted to a `String`. For your primary use case, you can simply use the first variant.